# Why partx can't read the partition table of some disks

Tags: partition, sfdisk

[partx](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/partx.8.html) fails to read the partition table of `/dev/sdb` on this system. Why does it return this 'failed to read partition table' shown below, instead of **null/empty** ? Will this 'failed' result always mean the device's partition table is damaged?

Notes: here the sdb can work fine as LVM without any partition！

```
    # pvs
      PV         VG                                        Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree  
      /dev/sda3  vgroot                                    lvm2 a--    89.00g   4.00m
      /dev/sda4  vgroot                                    lvm2 a--   746.78g 746.78g
      /dev/sdb   vgdata                                    lvm2 a--  <836.99g      0 

    # 
    # 
    # sfdisk -l /dev/sdb

    Disk /dev/sdb: 109262 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
    # 
    #
    # sfdisk -l /dev/sda

    Disk /dev/sda: 109262 cylinders, 255 heads, 63 sectors/track
    Units: cylinders of 8225280 bytes, blocks of 1024 bytes, counting from 0

       Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1          0+ 109262- 109263- 877647871+  ee  GPT
    sfdisk:                 start: (c,h,s) expected (0,0,2) found (0,0,1)

    /dev/sda2          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
    /dev/sda3          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
    /dev/sda4          0       -       0          0    0  Empty
    # 
    # 
    # partx -s /dev/sdb 
    partx: /dev/sdb: failed to read partition table
    # 
    # partx -s /dev/sda
    NR     START        END    SECTORS   SIZE NAME                 UUID
     1      2048     411647     409600   200M EFI System Partition 255f05dd-3c30-4eb5-b4ef-e222216eb27e
     2    411648    2508799    2097152     1G                      0eba1772-1106-4a63-bad6-6d20be988dba
     3   2508800  189171711  186662912    89G                      39fab8c9-bd96-47a2-b5db-495e43159055
     4 189171712 1755295710 1566123999 746.8G                      9e3d6237-5c7f-4443-8b60-b258052a8b32

    # 
    # 
    # pvdisplay /dev/sdb
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/sdb
      VG Name               vgdata
      PV Size               836.99 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes (but full)
      PE Size               4.00 MiB
      Total PE              214269
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          214269
      PV UUID               IsOr0G-UBTt-Qn1E-bx6R-dzvY-HqSE-bNiCaq

    # 
    # 
    # lsb_release -a
        LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
        Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
        Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
        Release:        7.4
        Codename:       Maipo
    # 
    #
```

Another system scense:

The following partx can directly output null/empty without any partition, why？
Notes: the following sdb can also work fine as LVM without any partition！

```
# 
# 
# partx  /dev/sdb
# 
# 
# 
# pvdisplay  /dev/sdb
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdb
  VG Name               vgdoc
  PV Size               600.00 GB / not usable 4.00 MB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size (KByte)       4096
  Total PE              153599
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          153599
  PV UUID               mMPvrE-NBP5-9n3J-77w5-57p0-1R7E-ggFCEj

# 
#  
# 
# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
Release:        5.5
Codename:       Tikanga
# 
#
```

1) My thought is that the partx should not exited with "failed to read ..." if the disk really has no partition.
   Notes: as you could see, the partx just only output null/empty in another system with the non-partition disk.

2) It is normal that the PV/LVMs can be created and used on the disk partitions, isn't it ？

```
 Device Boot Start     End   #cyls    #blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sda1   *      0+     25-     26-    204800   83  Linux
   /dev/sda2         25+  36404-  36380- 292215808   8e  Linux LVM
```

Comment: _lyklb_, would you mind please adding to your question? Please click [edit] and add the version of Linux of UNIX, and which version it is. Please do not reply with a Comment, as those can overflow quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partx` requires a partition table.  The results posted show there is no partition table on `sdb`.

This is different from a disk which has a partition table, but no partitions.  In that case, you could not have an LVM PV on that disk.

Compare the output of

- `blkid -o export /dev/sda`
- `blkid -o export /dev/sda3`
- `blkid -o export /dev/sdb`

You might also find `lsblk` useful.

---

`sdb` cannot be simultaneously formatted as an LVM PV and as a partition table, because they would include conflicting structures in the first sector.  To see that they would both include structures in the first sector, compare:

- `wipefs --no-act /dev/sda`
- `wipefs --no-act /dev/sda3`
- `wipefs --no-act /dev/sdb`

The "offset" column of `wipefs --no-act` is in bytes.

**You must be careful if you run `wipefs`.  It does what it sounds like.  However it is safe if you run `wipefs --no-act`.**

Comment: I have updated my post contents,  and my actual situation should be inconsistent with your above statement.

Comment: @lylklb eh. `partx` should be provided by `util-linux`.  If you want someone to verify nitpicky details about possibly different versions, you should post output of `rpm -q --whatprovides $(which partx)` , it should show the version number.

Comment: @lylklb I think you mis-read my second paragraph.  `sdb` has no partition table, and that is why you *can* have an LVM PV directly on `sdb`.

Comment: I have updated my post contents again.  And also I have used  both the native rpm and open source code from kernel.org,  but all the same failed results！

Comment: @lylklb did you try the same source code on RHEL 5.5?

Comment: I think that I would understand your meaning this time. I shall do it later .....  
And I also consider that the lower version of partx is more appropriate than its high version !

Comment: Yes, I have done it！  And also the same failed result with the higher version of partx on  RHEL 5.5！   So the problem should be due to the difference version of partx.